# mysql strips unicode slash while loading data

Tags: mysql, unicode, unicode-escapes

this is my csv file data sample. separated by '}'

> Q402342}Aho\u2013Corasick string matching algorithm
>
> Q8071262}Zhu\u2013Takaoka string matching algorithm
>
> Q8819520}Category:String matching algorithms

after importing in mysql , it shows

> |Q402342  | Ahou2013Corasick string matching algorithm
>
> | 8071262 | Zhuu2013Takaoka string matching algorithm
>
> |      13 | Category:String matching algorithms

after stripping '\'

How to fix this ..??

Following is the load command I used

LOAD DATA INFILE 'ids_articles.csv' INTO TABLE wikidata_terms CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '}' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: `\u2013` represents a single "unicode" character.  Do you want that 1 character or the 6 characters representing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html

In mysql the \ character is known as the escape character If you wish to enter a \ in a string you need to put 2 \ in your string so mysql knows you are not trying to escape your string so you would get:

```
Q402342}Aho\\u2013Corasick string matching algorithm
```